# Login form script has some errors which redirects the login page again to login page rather than allowing it to login in

Tags: php

I have tried many alternatives to this error but none of them works (all of them are commented) .Login form [login.php] is directed to scripts login.php [scripts/login.php] . In scripts/login.php file , the admin if block is working but login of providers from database is not working .

here is login.php

```
<?php

include_once "./msg/login.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/favicon.png">


      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>URBAN AMENITIES</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmain/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmain/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssmain/fontawesome.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header" class="header">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-capitalize">
            <div class="container">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="#" /> 
             </a>
               
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
               </button>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="show-menu">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                         <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                     </li>
                    
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="services.php">Services</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="how.php">How it Works</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="index.php">Instant Service</a>
                     </li>
                     
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="review.php">What Clients Say</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                     </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="feed.php">Feedback form</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px; width: 450px;">
    <div class="card">
       
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h3 class="text-center">Login for Service Providers</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="contact-form">
            <form action="scripts/login.php" method="post">
                    <label for=""><strong>Contact No : </strong></label>
                    <input id="contact" name="contact" class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Enter Your Contact No." minlength="10" maxlength="10" 
               required>
                    <label for=""><strong>Password :</strong></label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form- 
             control" placeholder="Enter Password." minlength="6" required><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn- 
                  block btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer >
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                  <div class="footer_blog_section">
                     <img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="#" /><br><br>
                     <p style="margin-top: 3px; font-size: 15px">URBAN AMENITIES</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-12">
                  <div class="item">
                     <h4 class="text-uppercase">Navigation</h4>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
                  <div class="item">
                     <h4 class="text-uppercase">Contact Info</h4>
                     <p><strong>Corporate Office Address:</strong></p>
                     <p><img src="imgs/phone_icon.png" alt="#" />+91 </p>
                     <p><strong>Customer Service:</strong></p>
                     <p><img src="imgs/location.png" alt="#" /> .</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                     <div class="item">
                     <h4 class="text-uppercase">Follow </h4>
                     <ul>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon1.jpg"><a href="http://localhost/homeservices/index.html"> Website</a></li>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon2.jpg"><a href=""> Gmail</a></li>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon3.jpg"><a href="https://"> Instagrm</a></li>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon4.jpg"><a href="https://"> Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon5.jpg"><a href="www.youtube.in"> Youtube</a></li>
                        <li><img src="imgs/icon6.jpg"><a href="https://"> LinkedIn</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>

               </div>


            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="copyright text-center">
            <p> URBAN AMENTIES &copy; <?= date("Y") ?>All Rights Reserved.</p>
         </div>
      </footer>
```

here is scripts/login.php

```
<?php

require_once 'session.php';
require_once 'helpers.php';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $contact = test_input($_POST["contact"]);
    $pass =test_input($_POST["password"]);
    if ($contact == "**" && $pass == "******") {
        $s = new stdClass();
        $s->name = "admin";
        $_SESSION['user'] = $s;
        header('Location: ../admin.php');
        exit();
    } else {
            $servername ="localhost";
            $username ="root";
            
            $dbname="services";
            
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=services; charset=utf8','***','******');
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM providers WHERE contact = '$contact' AND password = '$pass'";
                $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);  
                $statement->execute();  
                $providers = $statement->fetchAll();
                  // var_export($providers);
                
                /*if(isset($providers)){
                    header('Location: /msg/login.php?msg=success');
                    header('Location: /homeservices/provider.php'); 
                    
                    exit();

                }
                else{
                    header('Location: scripts/login.php?msg=failed');
                    exit();

                }*/

                foreach($providers as $provide=>$values) { 

                    if(($provide['contact'] =="$contact") &&  ($provide['password'] == "$pass")) { 
                        header('Location: ../login.php?msg=success');
                        header('Location: ../provider.php'); 
                        $_SESSION['user']=$provide;
                        exit();
                    }else { 
                        header('Location: ../login.php?msg=failed');
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
                $conn = null;
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?
As the admin this part is true:
 if ($contact == "7210110121" && $pass == "admin123") 

So that if will be processed accordingly, but the else part of it has completely different code, so the error can be anywhere in the entire "else" part.


Your code also contains quite a bit of info on your product. From your phone number, to urls and admin passwords. I would remove that info, it isn't needed for your question.

Comment: Yes ill make the changes. Yes it directs to admin.php when credentials are as follows in else block only there might be something wrong . There is no error as such but it just redirects again to login.php on pressing login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from the Providers "Block" of your code; you are redirecting twice.

redirections when called twice;

```
header('Location: ../login.php?msg=success');
header('Location: ../provider.php');
```

only the first one will take effect.

To fix this, remove the first header and keep only this;

```
header('Location: ../provider.php');
```

else, remove the second header. then on the form page where the login form is, do this;

```
if($_GET['msg'] == "success")
{
    header('Location: ../provider.php'); 
}
```

What this will do is it will check the `msg` returned and if `success`, it will redirect to the `provider.php`

Also remove the `foreach` statement. I do not see it's relevance in your code.

Ty this out let's see.

Comment: I am entering correct credentials but yet it goes to else block and displays incorrect credentials . Even after i tried the above code

Comment: inside the foreach there is an if block , I guess that condition is going wrong always ! Can you please check that

Comment: Am not sure why you need the foreach statement. You should just be doing a search in the database for the username and password and if you find them success else fail. Keep it simple. or perhaps you can explain what the foreach statement is doing?

Comment: Yes i just realized that foreach was not needed.

Comment: Ok. Can you please mark/accept my answer if I heped